# Floor Division and Modulo in ListView Django

Tags: django, django-views

With Django Listview, is it possible to display new columns that contain the values of floor division and modulo?

I have the following two models:

## models.py

```
class Model_Item(models.Model):
    item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False, unique = True)
    item_bottleperpack = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = False) # e.g. 100 bottles per pack

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item_name

class Model_ItemTransaction(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Model_Item, to_field = "item_name")
    item_sold = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = True) # in terms of bottle

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.item
```

With this listview:

## views.py

```
class View_Item(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Model_Item.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            sum_ = Sum("model_itemtransaction__item_sold")
            )
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            floor_division_ = F("sum_") // F("item_bottleperpack"),
            module_ = F("sum_") %% F("item_bottleperpack")
            )
        return queryset
```

Basically, if I have sold, say 650 bottles, and there is 100 bottles per pack, I would like the listview to display:

- **6** packs on the "floor-division" column, and
- **50** bottles on the "modulo" column.

Currently I am receiving the following errors with my current code

```
unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'F' and 'F'
and
unsupported operand type(s) for %%: 'F' and 'F'
```

and hoping someone could help me find any solution to this (and it does not have to be with [conditional expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/expressions/)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found a way to solve this, thanks to this [post](http://www.pfinn.net/custom-django-filter-tutorial.html).

First I cleaned the code at views.py,

## views.py

```
class View_Item(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Model_Item.objects.all()
        queryset = queryset.annotate(
            sum_ = Sum("model_itemtransaction__item_sold")
            )
        return queryset
```

then added this code file into the templatetags folder,

## app_filters.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name = "func_floor_division")
def func_floor_division(num, val):
    if num:
        floor_division = num // val
        return floor_division
    else:
        return None

@register.filter(name = "func_modulo")
def func_modulo(num, val):
    if num:
        modulo = num % val
        return modulo
    else:
        return None
```

and finally modified the tags in the html file.

## html

```
{% load app_filters %}
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Floor Division</th>
        <th>Modulo</th>
    </tr>

    {% for obj_ in object_list %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ obj_.sum_|func_floor_division:obj_.item_bottleperpack }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj_.sum_|func_modulo:obj_.item_bottleperpack }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Hope this helps for anyone who is encountering the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a new floor_division and module_ fields in your Model_Item, then you use the post save receiver to update the floor_division and module_ fields

```
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
class Model_Item(models.Model):
  item_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False, unique = True)
  item_bottleperpack = models.FloatField(null = True, blank = False) # e.g. 100 bottles per pack
  floor_division = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  module_ = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.item_name

def model_item_pre_save(sender, instance, created):
   item = Model_Item.objects.get(id=instance.id)
   item_transaction = Model_Transaction.objects.get(item_id=instance.id)
   item.floor_division = item_transaction.item_sold // item.item_bottleperpack
   item.module_ = item_transaction.item_sold %% item.item_bottleperpack


pre_save.connect(model_item_pre_save, sender=Model_Item)
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your method soon. By the way, I have found the solution and it is posted.

Comment: It's signals in Django. It's basically used to perform a task before an object of a model is saved to the database. Others are post_save, pre_delete and so on

Comment: Hey Bello, may I know which Django version that you are using? I tried running your code, but received a syntaxerror on "%%".

Answer (score 0):

According to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/db/models/expressions/:

Neither class `F` nor it's parent `Combinable` implement `__floordiv__`, so `//` is not implemented. `Combinable` does implement `__truediv__`, which is the `/` operator.

I haven't heard of the operator `%%` in Python, but `%` will work because `__mod__` is implemented in `Combinable`.

Try using `models.IntegerField` or `models.PositiveIntegerField` for `item_bottleperpack` and `item_sold`, and updating this line in views.py:

```
queryset = queryset.annotate(
        floor_division_ = F("sum_") / F("item_bottleperpack"),
        module_ = F("sum_") % F("item_bottleperpack")
        )
```

I'm assuming that Combinable will return an integer as the output of dividing two integers -- this might not be the case. If so, you might want to round down the result.

Comment: For some reason I receive the following error when running your code "operator does not exist: double precision % double precision". Could it be because I am on Django 1.11?

Comment: Strange. Did you change item_bottleperpack and item_sold to IntegerField in models.py? If they are still FloatField this would make sense.